# Is Minification used in Software Development?

Tags: minify, bundling-and-minification

Is very common to minify in web development, with html, css, js.

But wonder if is also use, for example, to develop a software in C#.
Can you develop a Photoshop, Final Draft, Adobe Acrobat... and minify its code?

Comment: What would be the point of minifying source code for compiled languages?

Comment: In other words, no: in general compiled languages lose all of the extra white space, long variable names, etc. during the process where the source is converted into assembly or bytecode.

Comment: Obfuscation is used sometimes to make reverse-engineering and tampering more difficult (but not impossible).  Bundling happens in the sense that many files of source code and statically-linked  external libraries can be merged into one executable.  One Windows EXE might be the result of hundreds of source code files and multiple external libraries.